# Putting quote into innerText

Tags: javascript, html

Im getting a random quote from an API which i want to display.
Im trying to build a Typing website as my first project to learn.
after getting the quote i assiign it to the Element with .innerText = quote.
but my text on the website shows "undefined"

```js
const random_api_url = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random"
const quoteDisplayElement = document.getElementById('word-display')

function getRandomQuote() {
    return fetch(random_api_url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(quote => console.log(quote.quote))
}

async function renderNewQuote() {
    const quote = await getRandomQuote()
    quoteDisplayElement.innerText = quote
}

renderNewQuote()
```

```html
<div class="word-display" id="word-display">Text</div>
```

Comment: Right after you console.log() the quote, `return` the quote.

Comment: Change `quote => console.log(quote.quote)` to `quote => quote.quote`

Comment: Barmar solved it thanks alot ! i also realize why it works now and didnt work earlier ty

Comment: Note that you can also do `({quote}) => quote`

Comment: connexo that worked ty also thanks for editing my post!

Answer (score 1):

Just `return` the quote in your last `then`:

```js
function getRandomQuote() {
    return fetch("https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({quote}) => quote)
}

async function renderNewQuote() {
    document.getElementById('quote-display').textContent = await getRandomQuote()
}

renderNewQuote()
```

```html
<div id="quote-display">Text</div>
```